# how do i get the position of the objects in my array?

Tags: javascript

I wan't to get the order of the objects in my array so I can store them to my database? But I don't know what to write in my for loop.

here's the code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var rootLimit = 8;
        $('ul.sortable').nestedSortable({
            handle: 'a',
            items: 'li',
            listType: 'ul',
            maxLevels: '3',
            toleranceElement: '> a',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                list = $(this).nestedSortable(
                    'toHierarchy', 
                    { startDepthCount: 0 }
                );
                var page_id = ui.item.find('> a').attr('data-page-id');
                console.log(list);
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    //Do something
                }
                $.post('/page/updatemenu/' + page_id, { 
                    list : list 
                }, function (data) {

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please put a fiddle over here jsfiddle.net. It will help us understand your question.

Comment: oke here"s my fiddle the meaning is that it looks for the item being replaced in the list en give the new position so i can store this in the database with ajax http://jsfiddle.net/kNPHe/ i am using laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
var index = $(ui.sender).index();
```

Comment: thank you and if i only want the order of the object that i just replaced? how do i write that any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for` you can use jQuery method `.each()`:

```
list.each(function(index, item){
    // do something with item or index of item
});
```